# How to make authorization nuxt 3 + laravel 10?

Tags: nuxt3, laravel-10, nuxt-auth

I need help.

I have API on laravel 10 and SSR app on Nuxt 3. So, how to make authorization with socials (google, facebook) with using laravel socialite + nuxt 3?

I found library sudebase/nuxt-auth, but I can’t understand how to use it with laravel

Maybe someone help me with it?